# Java Application Uses Relatively More CPU On Better PC Than Laptop

Tags: java, windows, performance, properties, performance-testing

I've got a tough question. I have a PC with a i5-3470 processor and a laptop with a i5-5200U processor. Naturally the 3470 cpu (which is in my desktop) is a lot faster, even when used single-core (see http://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i5-5200U-vs-Intel-Core-i5-3470/m22169vs2771). Yet for some reason when running the same java program on my PC requires more % of the cpu (when reading values from taskmanager) than my laptop (which has the 5200U processor).

Now I am not quite sure what the cause for this is. Where the program (which is an audioplayer that uses JavaFX's mediaplayer class to play audio) runs at an average of 0.4% cpu on my laptop with peaks reaching up to 1%, it runs at 0.5% on my PC with peaks reaching up to 1.8%. This obviously does not sound like a massive difference, but looking at both processor's specifications this is very unexpected behaviour. I'll list a bunch of facts to help you folks diagnose why this is happening:

-Both systems have the exact same java version

-Both systems use the exact same JVM options (see below)

-Both systems use the exact same program & .jar file

-Launching it from Netbeans IDE or outside of Netbeans IDE does not matter

-Both systems have very identical system properties as far as visible (see below)

-The PC also uses slightly more RAM (about 3mb more RAM) which might be caused by a certain system property. This piece of code gets called when the program launches: System.setProperty("sun.java2d.noddraw", "true"); which is a java system property that on some systems saves about 5mb of RAM.

Could you guys please help me figure out why the CPU usage is high on my PC with the i5 3470 compared to the laptop with the 5200U? Does it have to do with some system properties that are not visible on the list below, but that are activated on the one system and not on the other? Or are there other causes? Much thanks for the help in advance.

**Why this matters**

The program is supposed to be running at a very low profile, for experimental reasons. The difference in cpu time is also visible on PerfMon which is quite a bit more accurate than taskmanager. You'd expect the program to run at near 0.1% on the 3470 processor, which it doesnt.

**JVM options:**

-Xmaxjitcodesize2500k -XX:MaxPermSize=7m -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=3 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=7 -Xms5m -Xmx130m -XX:+UseParNewGC  -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled

**Relevant System Properties:**

java.awt.graphicsenv: sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment

os.arch: amd64

os.name: Windows 8.1

sun.java2d.noddraw: true

sun.jnu.encoding: Cp1252

java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\bin;C:\Windows
\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle
\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program 
Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32
\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel
\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel
\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) 
Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) 
Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program 
Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;

sun.management.compiler: HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers

java.awt.printerjob: sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob

file.encoding: UTF-8

sun.arch.data.model: 64

awt.toolkit: sun.awt.windows.WToolkit

java.vm.info: mixed mode

sun.io.unicode.encoding: UnicodeLittle

sun.cpu.endian: little

sun.desktop: windows

sun.cpu.isalist: amd64

Comment: I doubt that Task Manager is that accurate given all the other processes running, etc.  I would hardly consider a .5% increase as "high".  That is just basically noise.  Bigger things in life to worry about.

Comment: @OldProgrammer on PerfMon it also shows a very significant difference in performance, and the whole point of the program is to run at a low profile.

Comment: The 5000 series are two generations newer than the 3000 series.

Comment: Well have you run a Java profiler on the app?  Download yourkit 14 day trial.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey True, but the 5200 has a lower cache size, its clocked at 2.5ghz where the 3470 has larger cache size and 3.5-4ghz clock speed.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I will try this tomorrow. I am heading off to bed now. Thanks for your efforts so far, I appreciate it.

Comment: In my experience Haswell is ~30% faster for the same clock speed. Turbo mode for 5200U is 2.7 GHz which could be as fast as a 3.5 GHz Sandy Bridge, though being faster is surprising.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey it is Ivy Bridge though, not Sandy Bridge. Not sure if that makes a big difference.

Comment: @ImJustACowLol I don't think it does, but I don't have a number for IvyBridge vs Broadwell.

Comment: Are you sure, that you are running identical code? Since this is an audio player, you may be using different codecs on both systems. Or the codec uses different code paths, depending on the architecture.

Comment: @IInspectable The code is 100% the same. I dont know how Javafx mediaplayer class handles itself on different systems, but I doubt that that is the issue. It might have to do with a windowlistener I made for the JFrame so it can be moved around the users screen. Prior to implementing that and a timebar for the music. Since then the program started having very different CPU benchmarks.

Comment: *"I doubt that that is the issue"* - You should check instead. [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) from Sysinternals can list all modules mapped into a process. That may reveal other potential differences in the runtime environments as well.

Comment: @IInspectable will do during uni to first map my laptop. Thanks! I am going to be home in 4 hours so Ill map my desktop then :)

Comment: @OldProgrammer With the profiler I have found that java.lang.Thread.run() is  using 82% of the CPU usage on  my desktop and on my laptop it is at 90%. The remaining percentage is used by JNativeHook which for some reason requires relatively more processor time on my desktop than on my laptop. If it comes to looking at the individual threads, all threads have lower CPU time except for Swing-Shell, and the JNativeHook threads. All of them use anywhere between 1.5-2.5 times as much. No clue why this is happening.

Comment: @IInspectable I have found no odd files opened on my PC, and everything looked very similar to my laptop. In fact, it didn't show any specific codecs on that program opened anyways.

Comment: @OldProgrammer okay now I am noticing something off. java.lang.Thread.run() when profiling CPU usage with 'tracing' uses twice as much Time than on my laptop. On my laptop java.lang.thread.run and java.util.timerthread.run use equal amounts of time where on my desktop java.lang.thread.run uses twice as much than java.util.timerthread.run.

Comment: @OldProgrammer in short; java.timerthread.run() uses the exact same amount as on my laptop, but java.lang.thread.run() uses twice as much.